# Sql query for selecting the first 3 characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, stored-functions

I am trying to select the records from 2 tables in which the 1st table column named DESC (first 3 characters) should match with the project column of the 2nd table.

```
select SUBSTRING(a.[DESC],1,3) from Table1 a
left outer join Table2 b
on a.[DESC] = b.project
where SUBSTRING(a.[DESC],1,3) like b.project
```

Input:
1st Table DESC Column: 
Value: '2AB F YY'

2nd Table Project Column:
Value: '2AB'

Expected Output:
Return all the records of value 2AB

Comment: Input and expected output please ?

Comment: just edited my question

Comment: If at all possible you should consider fixing your data model. You seem to be storing multiple pieces of data in TableA. The project and a bunch of other stuff. This violates 1NF when you shove multiple data points together like that. And it forces your queries to be nonSARGable. Even a persisted computed column would be better.

Comment: @SeanLange thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: Not sure why somebody downvoted this. The question is clear and for somebody new to t-sql this might be easy to research or figure out. They posted all the information need to provide an answer.

Comment: @SeanLange that's what I was thinking too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PLEASE VOID USING RESERVED KEYWORDS LIKE DESC**

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/69760/4)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 ([DESC] varchar(255))
CREATE TABLE Table2 (Project varchar(255))
INSERT INTO Table1([DESC])values('2AB F YY')
INSERT INTO Table2(Project)values('2AB')
```

**Query 1**:

```
select SUBSTRING(a.[DESC],1,3)
from Table1 a
join Table2 b
on SUBSTRING(a.[DESC],1,3) = b.project
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/69760/4/0)**:

```
|     |
|-----|
| 2AB |
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select SUBSTRING(a.[DESC],1,3),* from Table1 a
join Table2 b
on SUBSTRING(a.[DESC],1,3) = b.project
```

Comment: You could also use LEFT(a.[Desc], 3) instead of substring since it is the first 3 characters.

Comment: Oh yeah that's great. Thanks