# Updating sql records while matching the first 3 characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, stored-functions

I am updating the records from 2 tables in which the 1st table column named DESCRIPTION(first 3 characters) should match with the project code column of the 2nd table. In case it's a match then Table 1 Description column is updated with the value of Table 2 Model column. I want to get the last 2 characters from Table 1 column DESCRIPTION to be added in my output, but the last 2 characters are not present in Table 2 column project.

```
update Table1
set Table1.[DESCRIPTION] = Table2.Model
from Table1
join Table2 on SUBSTRING(Table1.[DESCRIPTION],1,3) = Table2.projectcode
```

1st Table DESCRIPTION column: '2AB F YY'

2nd Table Project Column: Value: '2AB'

Expected Output: Return all the records of value 2AB Column result: '2AB YY'

Wrong Output: all the records of value starting other then 2AB

I am now looking to add the last 2 characters of the Description column in the updated value of description

Comment: Show us some more sample table data, and also the expected result. All as formatted text, i.e. no images.

Comment: You have already asked today 2 similar  questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58980575/sql-server-select-column-with-3-matching-characters and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58978676/sql-query-for-selecting-the-first-3-characters and accepted the answers you received. What is your problem now? Explain what you want.

Comment: @avery_larry `join` is `inner join`.

Comment: Yes indeed.  Comment deleted.

Comment: Hey, @forpas yes i have been stuck on a few questions today about sql

Comment: @forpas trying to update the records in the table when the first 3 characters matches with the value of another column in a different table. I am able to do till that part but what I am not able to do is to get the last 2 characters of the 1st column before its updated and add it to my updated column value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`RIGHT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/right-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function to get the last 2 characters of `[DESCRIPTION]`:

```
update t1
set t1.[DESCRIPTION] = t2.Model + ' ' + RIGHT(t1.[DESCRIPTION], 2)
from Table1 AS t1 inner join Table2 AS t2
on LEFT(t1.[DESCRIPTION], 3) = t2.projectcode
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9d1e681538d78e34eed9f098ce753d0f).